# Reloading a div without calling an external page

Tags: php, ajax, refresh

I have a dashboard set up to automatically refresh the page and data. I want to move away from that and only refresh divs. The only issue is that the data i am calling is from the back end and not a separate file. I have the following code:

```
 <script> var auto_refresh =setInterval(function({$('#test_refresh').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn("slow");}, 10000);
```

```
 <a href="#">Year to Date Sales<span id="test_refresh"> $<?=$this->YTDsales?></span></a>
```

Obviously the data is not refreshing, it's more or less of an effect. Is there a way to just refresh single php data? Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Answer #1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384708/reload-a-div-with-jquery-timer/5384761#5384761) solved my problem. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recomend to do a refresh via javascript, I would rather go through a simpler and cleaner solution try to do a polling or use websockets and update/get the information almost in real time.

look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511979/polling-data-from-server-most-effecient-and-practical-way-setup) and you may get a clearer concept of what I'm suggesting and this is a [practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code) of a long polling in php

I hope that helps,
cheers!